# copying file into directory; Shell, Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to copy a file under path:

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/file
```

into a directory with path:

```
dir7/dir9/dir10
```

I am using the cp command like this:

```
cp dir1/dir2/dir3/file dir7/dir9/dir10
```

But I get the error:

```
cannot create regular file 'dir7/dir9/dir10': No such file or directory
```

But the directory definitely exists. I am so confused, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: can you show the output of `tree` command?

Comment: Does `/dir7/dir9/dir10` exist?

Comment: Yes it does. I cd into it like this:

cd dir7/dir9/dir10 

And it works. Same with /dir1/dir2/dir3/file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Always use absolute directory paths if you are not certain about relative path.**

In your case, if dir7/dir9/dir10 lies in / directory then provide full path to cp command like,

```
cp dir1/dir2/dir3/file /dir7/dir9/dir10
```

if it lies in /home/usr/ directory then provide it as,

```
cp dir1/dir2/dir3/file /home/usr/dir7/dir9/dir10
```

This applies to first argument also,

```
cp <absolute path> <absolute path>
```

Comment: I tried cp /dir1/dir2/dir3/file /dir7/dir9/dir10

But it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because dir10 does not exist. Linux is trying to copy a file into a folder that has not yet been created. You will have to run the following command first:

```
    mkdir -p dir7/dir9/dir10
    cp dir1/dir2/dir3/file dir7/dir9/dir10
```